# PSCP file to multiple servers

Tags: linux

I'm trying to upload a file to a list of servers, and everything says to use -h to read the list but it's not working.

This is on windows with the latest available pscp package, and -h is not an option in the help. Is this not possible on windows?

I made a file called servers.txt with the ips and port in it

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<>
pscp -h
PuTTY Secure Copy client

Development snapshot 2019-02-14.8555064

Usage: pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
       pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target
       pscp [options] -ls [user@]host:filespec

Options:

-V        print version information and exit

-pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit

-p        preserve file attributes

-q        quiet, don't show statistics

-r        copy directories recursively

-v        show verbose messages

-load sessname  Load settings from saved session

-P port   connect to specified port

-l user   connect with specified username

-pw passw login with specified password

-1 -2     force use of particular SSH protocol version

-4 -6     force use of IPv4 or IPv6

-C        enable compression

-i key    private key file for user authentication

-noagent  disable use of Pageant

-agent    enable use of Pageant

-hostkey aa:bb:cc:...
         manually specify a host key (may be repeated)

-batch    disable all interactive prompts

-proxycmd command
            use 'command' as local proxy

-unsafe   allow server-side wildcards (DANGEROUS)

-sftp     force use of SFTP protocol

-scp      force use of SCP protocol

-sshlog file

-sshrawlog file
            log protocol details to a file

Answer (score 1):

Are you confusing the pscp you get from [Parallel SSH (pssh)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/) with the pscp command you get as part of [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)?  They are completely different selections of tools.  While the command named 'pscp' exists in both they function very differently.

The putty pscp does not support the feature you are looking for.

If you need to do something from Windows fire up powershell and use a command like this perhaps.

```
Get-Content dests.txt | ForEach-Object {
  pscp.exe source $_
}
```

Another  option would be to install your favorite Distro under the Windows Subsystem for Linux, and then install the pssh package and use the pscp from there, if you really want that 'parallel ssh pscp' functionality.

Comment: Thanks, i probably am confusing them which is why i wanted to clearly indicate which i was using. Appreciate the links too